# Are there alternatives functions for the gamma function that was used as generalisation for the factorials?

Tags: real-analysis, special-functions, gamma-function

Now asked on HSM [here](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/17363/are-there-alternatives-functions-for-the-gamma-function-that-was-used-as-general).

---

> $$\Gamma(x)= \int_0^ \infty e^{-t}t^{x-1}dt \ \ \ \  \ \ \ x>0.  $$

Bohr and Mollerup showed that the gamma  function is the only positive  function $f$ defined on $(0,\infty)$ that has these properties

1. $f(x+1)=xf(x)$
2. $f(1)=1$
3. $f(x)$ is a continuous
4. $f(x)$  is log convex

But before Bohr and Mollerup  why did Euler or Bernoulli  chose this function ? there are infinite many  positive continuous function $f$ st $f(x+1)=xf(x)$, was there any alternatives functions for the gamma function as a generalisation for the factorial function that was used before and now we stopped? If there is one then why do we stop using it? If there isn't one then why and how did Euler and other found the "Only" "natural" generalisation for the factorial function centuries before   Bohr and Mollerup as somehow they knew that this solution is unique.

Comment: Possibly a question for https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2094/why-were-18th-century-mathematicians-interested-in-extending-the-factorial-to-no

Comment: and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9746/who-invented-the-gamma-function

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_gamma_function, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudogamma_function